# Schedule SSIS Package using C#

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

What I want to do, is to schedule a SSIS package, using C#. the missing part is, how to tell the agent that this schedulare is for the SSIS package "X", Here is my code :

```
Server srv = new Server();

//Define an Operator object variable by supplying the Agent (parent JobServer object) and the name in the constructor. 
Operator op = new Operator(srv.JobServer, "AC_Operator") { NetSendAddress = "Network1_PC" };

//Create the operator on the instance of SQL Server Agent. 
op.Create();

//Define a Job object variable by supplying the Agent and the name arguments in the constructor and setting properties. 
Job jb = new Job(srv.JobServer, "AC_Job");

//Specify which operator to inform and the completion action. 
jb.OperatorToNetSend = "AC_Operator";
jb.NetSendLevel = CompletionAction.Always;

//Create the job on the instance of SQL Server Agent. 
jb.Create();

//Define a JobStep object variable by supplying the parent job and name arguments in the constructor. 
JobStep jbstp = new JobStep(jb, "AC_Job_Step");
jbstp.OnSuccessAction = StepCompletionAction.QuitWithSuccess;
jbstp.OnFailAction = StepCompletionAction.QuitWithFailure;

//Create the job step on the instance of SQL Agent. 
jbstp.Create();

//Define a JobSchedule object variable by supplying the parent job and name arguments in the constructor. 

JobSchedule jbsch = new JobSchedule(jb, "AC_Job_Schedule");

//Set properties to define the schedule frequency, and duration. 
jbsch.FrequencyTypes = FrequencyTypes.Daily;
jbsch.FrequencySubDayTypes = FrequencySubDayTypes.Minute;
jbsch.FrequencySubDayInterval = 30;
TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
jbsch.ActiveStartTimeOfDay = ts1;

TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);
jbsch.ActiveEndTimeOfDay = ts2;
jbsch.FrequencyInterval = 1;

DateTime d = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
jbsch.ActiveStartDate = d;

//Create the job schedule on the instance of SQL Agent. 
jbsch.Create();
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You will need to configure `jbstp` to be of type SSIS and then you should be able to specify the details (name, config files, etc)

Comment: Yes it came to my mind, but I didn't know how to do it! Any détails ?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are needing to do is set the jobstep's [SubSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstep.subsystem%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and then build your [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstep.command%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). In comparing the .NET generated code to a SQL Agent created job, the only difference I noticed was the assignment of the [DatabaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstep.databasename%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) property so I set that as well.

You'll also undoubtedly want to look at [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) to figure out how to configure and invoke your package or you can cheat like I do and use dtexecui or the Agent to build out the SET and other commands and then paste those in as the source command.

```
        //Define a JobStep object variable by supplying the parent job and name arguments in the constructor. 
        JobStep jbstp = new JobStep(jb, "AC_Job_Step");
        jbstp.OnSuccessAction = StepCompletionAction.QuitWithSuccess;
        jbstp.OnFailAction = StepCompletionAction.QuitWithFailure;

        string command = string.Empty;
        command = @"/FILE ""C:\sandbox\SSISHackAndSlash2008\SSISHackAndSlash2008\EzAPI_Recipe01.dtsx""  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E";
        jbstp.SubSystem = AgentSubSystem.Ssis;
        jbstp.DatabaseName = "master";
        jbstp.Command = command;

        //Create the job step on the instance of SQL Agent. 
        jbstp.Create();
```

Comment: Thank you, you were very helpful ^^